# Получить из input() только число

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать так, чтобы бралась определённая информация.

Например:

1. простой способ:

   ```
   П: Сколько тебе лет? 
   Ч: 22. 
   П: О тебе 22!
   ```
2. Сложный способ:

   ```
   П: сколько тебе лет? 
   Ч: Мне 22 года. 
   П: О тебе 22!
   ```

Мне непонятно, как реализовать второй - сложный способ.

`П` - программа, `Ч` - человек.

Comment: Программу вы можете научить извлекать информацию. Но нет гарантии, что человек ее даст. Пример: П — Сколько тебе лет? Ч — Я совершеннолетняя, а ты? П — я еще неопытный бот, недавно закончил тестирование.

Comment: В примере "простой" способ ничем не проще "сложного" :) Из-за точки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```
askage = input()

age = 0

for i in askage.split():
    if i.isdigit():
       age = i

print(f'О, тебе {age}!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Это метод подходит, если ответ будет "Мне столько-то лет/года":

```
question = input("Сколько тебе лет?\t")
print(f"О тебе {question.split(' ')[1]}")
```

Comment: Ну то есть довольно бесполезный метод :)

Comment: @Эникейщик,  человек просил под конкретную фразу, вот и сделал... так-что... каков вопрос, таков ответ